# failed to install grub-install dev / sda

Tags: grub

I decided to go to the Elementary, but installation issues "critical error", saying "failed to install grub-install dev / sda" (not literally wrote). How to fix it can be.
Notebook Asus K56CB. Mount as Rufus, and UltraISO, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to the internet when installing elementary OS. This happened to me and connecting to the internet solved the problem.